# shinyapps.io: how to upload files automatically from variables placed in a source file?

Tags: shiny-server, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm writing a shinydasboard app that will run on shinyapps.io. 
Inputs of this app consist in several files, placed in different locations. To upload these files, the first implementation was a series of fileInput buttons, but this is redundant and confusing for users. 
Luckily, users already have a configuration file containing all the paths pointing to the files to upload; so, the idea is that users will upload only this config file and the app will be able to automatically upload files from local file-system, without user interaction.

The "pipeline" will be:

```
ui.R:
fileInput(inputId = "configFile", label = "Configuration file", multiple = F)


server.R:
configFile <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$configFile
    if (is.null(inFile)) {return()}
    return(source(inFile$datapath))
  })
```

The config file looks like:

```
fileA <- "Examples/Complete/BasicData/fileA.txt"
fileB <- "Examples/Complete/BasicData/fileB.csv"
```

Then, for each variables loaded with `source(inFile$datapath)`, the app should be able to follow the corresponding path (i.e.: `"Examples/Complete/BasicData/fileA.txt"`) to the local file-system of the user and automatically upload each file.

How can it be done? Thank you!